# How to get a Yelp access token

Tags: api, swift2, yelp

I am trying to use the yelp fusion api but cannot seem to find out how to format the url. I have read the get started page but do not understand it. I just need to know where to put what. This is what I have so far:
`https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ID&client_secret="CLIENT SECRET"`
When I load this url it says "VALIDATION_ERROR." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got the request working and got a token, but now I need to know where to put it in the url. Where would put the access token?

Comment: how did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The grant_type,client_id and client_secret should be sent in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format in the POST call.

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET'
```

Comment: Kindly completely define your answer. So that other users can also take help from your input. And posting links are not the best option you should have written some of the code so if the target link is taken out your answer should still make sense.